# Incorrect Key Length for Padded Encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption

I have been having a problem with doing padded encryption. I think I have isolated the issue to this function:

```
static String AESEncryptStringWithPassword(String s, String p) throws...{
    //function to create key from string password
    SecretKey secret = deriveAESKey(p);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext);
    return str;

}
```

Down the line when I go to decrypt I will get an error like so: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher.

I have checked and this method is the origin of the bad length string. No further methods corrupt it. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I have based my code on the question here: [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)

EDIT: I have changed the encoding slightly to use String(byte[], charset) instead. However now with defaultcharset I have an appropriate string length and with utf-8 I do not.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion between byte[] and String throughout the program seemed to be the problem. Kept it as byte[] as much as possible and then it worked.

So, lesson learned: Careful converting between byte[] and String.